# How to get TextChoice enum value in __str__ method

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is how I tried defining models in `models.py`

```
from django.db import models

class Country(models.Model):
    class Countries(models.TextChoices):
        US = 'US', 'United States'
        EP = 'EP', 'Europe'
        IND = 'IN', 'India'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=2,
                        choices=Countries.choices,
                        blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return getattr(self.Countries, self.name)
```

the **str** invocation just gives two letter country code. How do I get full info like `US (United states)` or `US, United States`

When I add country manually in `admin` It shows full name. It must be getting it from somehow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [**`get_FOO_display()`** (Django Doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) method

```
class Country(models.Model):
    # other fields
    def __str__(self):
        return "{value} ({display_value})".format(value=self.name, display_value=self.get_name_display())
```